# Interger being passed but a Char value expected expected?

Tags: java, class, methods

Hi im trying to make a letter guessing game with 3 random letters, when i try to get a value using the below code it always a returns as an int to the other program bellow im trying to receive it as a letter but can't figure it out.

```
 import java.util.Random;

 public class CodeLetter {
 private char letterValue;     
 int count = 8;
 Random rnd = new Random ();


 public char codeLetter(){

letterValue = (char)(rnd.nextInt(5)+'A');
System.out.println(letterValue);
return letterValue;


 }

 }
```

The code that calls the above code using line

```
  letter1 = codeLetter.codeLetter();
```

but once it is printed to screen it still holds an int value, not the char.
This program requires both classes as requirments

```
public class CodeBreaker {
    private char letter1;
    private char letter2;
    private char letter3;

    CodeLetter codeLetter = new CodeLetter();


    public void CodeBreaker(){
        //Welcome Screen
                System.out.println("Welcome to CODEBREAKER ");
                System.out.println("you have 6 tries to guess the secret 3 letter code.");
                System.out.println("The letters Range from A to E");
                System.out.println("Goodluck");
                System.out.println("The code has no repeat letters");
                //end
                letter1 = codeLetter.codeLetter();
                letter2 = codeLetter.codeLetter();
                letter3 = codeLetter.codeLetter();

                System.out.println(letter1 + letter2 + letter3);
    }
    /*public boolean done(){

    }
    /*private boolean isValid*char){
        //- Is the given letter valid?
    }*/

    public void getGuess(/*int*/){
        //- Get guess #
    }
    public void checkGuess(){
        //- Verify the guess
    }
    public void display(){
        //- Display the secret code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run your program. Bellow output I have found.

```
Welcome to CODEBREAKER 
you have 6 tries to guess the secret 3 letter code.
The letters Range from A to E
Goodluck
The code has no repeat letters
B
B
C
199
```

**If I understand you correctly** You have problem with that `199`. I assume, you want `BBC` instead of `199`. It is because you use `+` sign with the char type that will implicitly converted into integer and do arithmetic operation. So you have problem with the following line `System.out.println(letter1 + letter2 + letter3);`. You can print separately those different char.

BTW, your `codeletter()` method return char as expected. Also for this kind of language behavior you can researh on [Strongly vs Weakly type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator is *either* a [numeric additive operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) *or* a [string concatenation operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1).

The Java Language Specification, [§15.18. Additive Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18), say:

> If the type of either operand of a `+` operator is `String`, then the operation is string concatenation.
>
> Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the `+` operator must be a type that is convertible ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to a primitive numeric type, [...]

Your code (`letter1 + letter2 + letter3`) is a `char + char + char` expression, and since none of them are `String` values, it's a numeric add expression.

You have many choices for fixing that:

1. Create a `String` directly from a `char[]`:

   ```
   new String(new char[] { letter1, letter2, letter3 })
   ```

   This is the most efficient way, both performance-wise and memory-wise.
   *I recommend doing it this way.*
2. Convert the first letter to a `String`, so the `+` operator becomes a string concatenation operator:

   ```
   String.valueOf(letter1) + letter2 + letter3
   ```

   This is shorter to write, but is less efficient, since it first creates a temporary string, then have to perform a string concatenation to build the final string.
3. Another way to convert the first letter to a `String`:

   ```
   Character.toString(letter1) + letter2 + letter3
   ```

   Internally, `Character.toString()` calls `String.valueOf()` *(Java 8)*, so it's really the same, and you can use whichever you like best.
4. Perform the string concatenation directly, so you don't need to create the initial temporary string:

   ```
   new StringBuilder().append(letter1).append(letter2).append(letter3).toString()
   ```

   Very verbose.
5. Start with an empty string:

   ```
   "" + letter1 + letter2 + letter3
   ```

   This is the most terse way to write it. A lot of people like this way because of the terseness, and I believe the minimal overhead of the extra string will even be eliminated in Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`Character.forDigit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit(int,%20int))